# Custom OutputCacheProvider, method Add, how to get raw value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I am try to implementation my own OutputCacheProvider for asp.met mvc 5 using redis.
And I can't to get value from a parameter "entry" (object) into method Add.
Declaration:

```
public override object Add(string key, object entry, DateTime utcExpiry)
```

When debugging, method Add get entry as System.Web.Caching.CachedVary, but it is protected class, and there is no way to get raw value.

Solution by microsoft - RedisOutputCacheProvider, can't help me, because i see there the trouble too.

May be it is configured into web.config, then the question is how?

Thanks for any solutions.

Comment: As a non-expert on this specific topic I cannot fully check if it fits fully [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). So please check and give  more information where needed by editing your own question. End of Triage Review.

Comment: My code is not important for the quesion, who know the problem easily understand what is the question. Thanks for remark.